# Searchable fiter for d3 donut charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, d3.js, donut-chart

Hello I have a D3 script that outputs a bunch of donut charts and I am looking for a way to filter and search out keywords in the name of the first columns of my data. I would like to be able to do this live and am not looking for a way to filter the data specifically just but a search bar or some other way to allow users to search and filter through the donut charts. My biggest problem is incorporating the search element into the d3.csv() part I understand how to make a searchbar and have incorporated an example of one that I would like to be able to search through my data. **I have done more research and perhaps using jquery would help.**

Here is my D3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Search Box Example 1</title>
    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
    <!-- CSS styles for standard search box -->
    <style type="text/css">
      #tfheader{
        background-color:#c3dfef;
      }
      #tfnewsearch{
        float:right;
        padding:20px;
      }
      .tftextinput{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
        border:1px solid #0076a3; border-right:0px;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
      }
      .tfbutton {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        border: solid 1px #0076a3; border-right:0px;
        background: #0095cd;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00adee), to(#0078a5));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00adee,  #0078a5);
        border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
      }
      .tfbutton:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #007ead;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0095cc), to(#00678e));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0095cc,  #00678e);
      }
      /* Fixes submit button height problem in Firefox */
      .tfbutton::-moz-focus-inner {
        border: 0;
      }
      .tfclear{
        clear:both;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- HTML for SEARCH BAR -->
      <div id="tfheader">
        <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="http://www.google.com">
                <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q" size="21" maxlength="120"><input type="submit" value="search" class="tfbutton">
        </form>
      <div class="tfclear"></div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    svg {
      padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
    }

    .arc {
      stroke: #fff;
    }

    </style>
    <body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>



    var radius = 74,
        padding = 10;

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#2B8429"]);

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius)
        .innerRadius(radius - 30);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

    d3.csv("data1.csv", function(error, data) {
      color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "device"; }));

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) {
          return {name: name, population: +d[name]};
        });
      });

      var legend = d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("class", "legend")
          .attr("width", radius * 2)
          .attr("height", radius * 2)
        .selectAll("g")
          .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

      legend.append("rect")
          .attr("width", 18)
          .attr("height", 18)
          .style("fill", color);

      legend.append("text")
          .attr("x", 24)
          .attr("y", 9)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d; });

      var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll(".pie")
          .data(data)
        .enter().append("svg")
          .attr("class", "pie")
          .attr("width", radius * 2)
          .attr("height", radius * 2)
        .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

      svg.selectAll(".arc")
          .data(function(d) { return pie(d.ages); })
        .enter().append("path")
          .attr("class", "arc")
          .attr("d", arc)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.name); });

      svg.append("text")
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text(function(d) { return d.device; });

    var peopleTable = tabulate(data, ["device"]);

    });

    </script>
```

Here is some example data:

```
State,Under 5 Years,5 to 13 Years,14 to 17 Years,18 to 24 Years,25 to 44 Years,45 to 64 Years,65 Years and Over
AL,310504,552339,259034,450818,1231572,1215966,641667
AK,52083,85640,42153,74257,198724,183159,50277
AZ,515910,828669,362642,601943,1804762,1523681,862573
AR,202070,343207,157204,264160,754420,727124,407205
CA,2704659,4499890,2159981,3853788,10604510,8819342,4114496
CO,358280,587154,261701,466194,1464939,1290094,511094
CT,211637,403658,196918,325110,916955,968967,478007
DE,59319,99496,47414,84464,230183,230528,121688
DC,36352,50439,25225,75569,193557,140043,70648
FL,1140516,1938695,925060,1607297,4782119,4746856,3187797
GA,740521,1250460,557860,919876,2846985,2389018,981024
HI,87207,134025,64011,124834,356237,331817,190067
ID,121746,201192,89702,147606,406247,375173,182150
IL,894368,1558919,725973,1311479,3596343,3239173,1575308
IN,443089,780199,361393,605863,1724528,1647881,813839
IA,201321,345409,165883,306398,750505,788485,444554
KS,202529,342134,155822,293114,728166,713663,366706
KY,284601,493536,229927,381394,1179637,1134283,565867
```

I have seen examples of how to filter by set values but would like to have a search bar. Keep in mind I am relatively new to D3 and JS.